# LibGDX How can I make a label bigger?

Tags: android, libgdx

My label right now is very small. How can I change its size?
How/where can I change the BitmapFont?

This is what I have right now:

```
scoreLabel = new Label((String.format("%01d", score)), new Label.LabelStyle(new BitmapFont(), com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color.WHITE));

table.add(scoreLabel).expandX();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to work with fonts I strongly suggest you to create a separate class.
[Here](https://github.com/angelnavarro/Gdx-Freetype-Example/blob/master/core/src/com/pixnbgames/gdx_freetype_example/util/FontFactory.java) you'll find a complete working example. But basically you need to save a desired font to internal memory (android\assets). Then you should generate a font:

```
private BitmapFont generateFont(String fontName, String characters) {
        FreeTypeFontParameter parameter = new FreeTypeFontParameter();
        parameter.characters = characters;
        parameter.size = 24;

        FreeTypeFontGenerator generator = new FreeTypeFontGenerator( Gdx.files.internal(fontName) );
        BitmapFont font = generator.generateFont(parameter);

        generator.dispose();    
        return font;
    }
```

`parameter.size` is the param you would want to change to make your label bigger.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the size of the Label but the font size won't change. You have to use a bigger font. I use this code to create BitmapFonts with custom font:

```
float size = 12;
FreeTypeFontGenerator generator = new FreeTypeFontGenerator(fontFile);
FreeTypeFontParameter parameter = new FreeTypeFontParameter();
parameter.size = size;
BitmapFont bitmapFont = generator.generateFont(parameter);
```

If you use the BitmapFont() constructor you will receive 15pt sized font which is located here: *com/badlogic/gdx/utils/arial-15.fnt*